# Android show add google account screen if none exists

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an android application that allows users log in with their google account if none google account exists.I have already known how to start Add Account activity
Code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT));
```

This screen let user choose type account.I want to skip that screen.I wanna show Add google account screen(just like Google  Play do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  AccountManager acm = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
      acm.addAccount("com.google", null, null, null, this, 
      null, null);
```

Add in Manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.But how can I retrieve user's gmail after user complete sign in and come back to main activity.I know use AccountManager class which retrieve user account

Comment: What do you mean.finish() of main activity?

Comment: Yeah.I know.But I already didn't call it.I mean here how can I detect when user complete sing in process and after that I can retrieve user's gmail

Comment: Sorry,after user complete sign in  process.How "Validate if google account added or not ".

Comment: in onActivityResult method call list of your phone accounts. If list contains some new account that sign in complete if no then cancel

Comment: I tried.But when I completed sign in  process. onActivityResult() wasn't called.Something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

use this to retrieve google account if exists

```
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            possibleEmail = account.name;
        }
    }
```